# Code to YouTube Live Stream

Tags: iframe, youtube, stream, embed, live

I use this script for my LIVE Stream and it works great.  However, I have two LIVE broadcasts that run simultaneously on the same channel.  Is it possible to access the other LIVE stream using a similar code?

Comment: Try adding code to your question.

Comment: <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="270" id="vid_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[CHANNEL_ID]&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=1&amp;autohide=1" width=""></iframe>